# Need a short example for rotating background colors upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, database, onclick

I'm slowly working out this `this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'` and how it can make things go red when I click!

I want the button I have applied this rule to rotate colors by this order upon the click events:
red, orange, green, red, orange, green, etc..

It's for a purpose! Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? all help welcomed :)

Also in the long run I want people to click either red, orange or green and record these results in a database.

A point in the correct direction would be great :)

Comment: Seriously Benjamin, are you really editing a question from 18 feb just to get two points? :S

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `style.backgroundColor` works. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/A76FY/)